# Magento MP4 downloadable products are not opening with the correct encoding/format

Tags: magento, download, mp4, product

My site has downloadable products which are MP4 files. On completion of an order the files are available to download in the customer account area as usual.

When I download the file in Chrome it downloads without a problem (in Safari it only plays in the browser, which is weird).

But the problem is Firefox. When I click a download link I get this:

[image]

I've also tried it in IE6 - where it downloads, but in an unrecognised format.

I think it's probably to do with how the browser encodes the files, but I'm not sure. It looks as though an MP4 file has been opened as a plain text document. Is there a way that Magento can ensure that it opens the file to download as an MP4?

Any help would be much, much appreciated!

Comment: I think that I ultimatley just need to force the MIME type of mP4 onto all downloads.

Comment: Think you answered your own question. ;)

Comment: @B00MER - I did try this with a hack in core > Mage > Downloadable > Helper > File.php. I made it so that the MIME type would be 'video/mp4' regardless of the filetype, but it didn't seem to work. If anyone has any other ideas please let me know.

Comment: Are you using the egoods feature, I take it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I managed to get it working by changing admin settings:

Go to: **System > Configuration > Catalog > Downloadable Product Options**

Under Use Content-Disposition change the ‘inline’ value to ‘attachment’

The file now downloads properly in Firefox when I click on the download link